# Problem with Joining to voice chat on telegram desktop via Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: telegram

I have problem for joining the voice chat in the group for telegram desktop:

[image]

I am using the proxy connection type to bypass filters and my OS is Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: I am having the same issue as well, in Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS, and im using latest telegram version too(4.0.0), tried restarting, re opening, nothing works

Comment: I also cannot join any voice chat on Telegram desktop since yesterday. I am using Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS. Is it because of the latest update of Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

if it doesn’t work for you now, like me, then wait for version 4.0.3 or download the beta version, it worked for me there